# For loop conditional statement for if a List<Contact> contains an element

Tags: list, map, contains

I have some code like this. While the conditionals I have are working fine what I cannot check for is if Contact lCon is NOT contained in the sfdcList. I have been trying to find a way to set up a Set or List and contains() method to do this but it all doesn't seem to work as I expect.

lookerByIds is a `Map<Id, List<Contact>>` So the intent here is that each element of the sfdcList for a given Id is checked against a list of contacts by Id. See if they have conditionals like so and if the lCon list is in the sfdcList at all. Then do something else.

```
for(Contact con : sfdcList){

            //specifies the same key value pair as the queried Contact
            for(Contact lCon : lookerByIds.get(con.AccountId)) {

                if(con.Email !=Null && lCon.Email !=Null) {
                    //compares email values 
                    if(!con.Email.equalsIgnoreCase(lCon.Email)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(con.Email.equalsIgnoreCase(lCon.Email)) {
                        //adjusts record
                        if(con.status__c == Null)
                        {
                            con.status__c = 'Billing Contact';
                            syncList.add(con);
                            //system.debug(con);

                        }
                        if(con.status__c != Null && !con.status__c.contains('Billing Contact')) {
                            con.status__c = con.status__c + ';Billing Contact';
                            syncList.add(con);
                            //system.debug(con);
                        }
                        if(con.LastName.equals('Accounts Payable') && con.status__c.contains('Billing Contact')) {
                            continue;
                        }
                           //system.debug(con);
                    }
                    else {

                    Contact bub = new Contact(LastName = 'Accounts Payable', AccountId = lCon.AccountId, status__c = 'Billing Contact', Email = lCon.Email);
                    syncList.add(bub);
                    }
```

Comment: you can put if check to match the Id, inside second for loop.
`if(con.Id != lCon.Id)`

Comment: In this case they all share the same Id (Account ID), I can only compare emails.

lCon is from an external data source that only had email addresses and SFDC Account Ids

Comment: As I understood from your question like you want to check if lCon is contains in sfdcList or vice versa. That's why I tell to compare the lCon.Id with con.Id.

Comment: Yes but lCon is a List<Contact> of a map keyed by the same Id as SfdcList AccountID,

What I need to do is see if lCon email address exists in the sfdcList

Comment: Okay, how lookerByIds map form, is this data come from the lighting component.

Comment: This data comes from an external HTTP callout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to test for which elements in set 1 are not in set 0 is as follows:

```
 set1.removeAll(set0);
```

After the operation, `set1` will only have elements not in `set0`.  hence it is a destructive operation so you may choose to do a deepclone of the set before the `removeAll` method.

So, for your OP, you need two sets -

- `map<Id,Contact[]> sfdcContactsByAccountId // the keyset`
- `lookerByIds // the keyset`

  ```
  lookerByIds.keySet().removeAll(sfdcContactsByAccountId);
  ```

> **removeAll(setOfElementsToRemove)**
>
> Removes the elements in the specified set from the original set if they are present.
>
> **Signature**
>
> public Boolean removeAll(Set setOfElementsToRemove)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> setOfElementsToRemove
>    Type: Set
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> This method returns true if the original set changed as a result of the call.